# Factorial of a number, How does the machine interpret it?

Tags: python, math, computer-science

today I was practicing some mathematics simple problems and was coding the Factorial of a number, and wanted to understand something in particular.

```
def fact (n):
    if (n==0):
        return 1
    else:
        return n*fact (n-1)

x = int(input("Enter x : "))
y = fact(x)
print("{}! = {}".format (x,y))
```

This part `return n*fact (n-1)`
On the way, I interpret this  `n * fact` would be like a number multiplication by fact, by himself, and then placing `(n-1)` it would be something like x = x * (x - 1) but then if we do this with a number like 5 it would be 5 = 5 * (5-1). So I don't understand how the machine goes to 1 or 0.
So I was thinking that the machine goes back and back until it gets in 0 because of the variable `return`.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no such thing as multiplying a number by a function. The correct order of operation is: `n * (fact(n-1))` => `5 * (fact(5-1))` => `5 * (fact(4))` => `5 * 24` => `120`

Comment: That's an answer, sshashank

Comment: So you are basically saying that the computer interprets the operation like this :  n * (fact(n-1)) => 5 * (fact(5-1)) => 5 * (fact(4)) => 5 * 24 => 120 ?

Comment: This concept is called recursion. Checkout this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QqoEmoCsmUg

Comment: If you write `n*fact (n-1)` with spacing according to the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) you'll get `n * fact(n - 1)`. Now you can see much better that it's not multiplying `n` with a function and then doing some strange `(n-1)` stuff, but that there is `n` multiplied with the result of a function call.

Comment: Hello, thanks to everyone for your replays, I think I didn't explain myself well, basically, I just was asking about how the computers interpret the exponentials, and I just throw a theory out there, and thanks to A.J. Uppal he explained it pretty well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> On the way, I interpret this n * fact would be like a number multiplication by fact, by himself, and then placing (n-1)

What you are seeing is called [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)). The definition says:

> Recursion in computer science is a method of solving a problem where the solution depends on solutions to smaller instances of the same problem.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)) Such problems can generally be solved by iteration, but this needs to identify and index the smaller instances at programming time. At the opposite, recursion solves such recursive problems by using functions that call themselves from within their own code.

`fact` being a function in your program (defined by `def`) which also returns some value is being used in recursive calls.

The recursive functions must obey three important laws:

1. A recursive algorithm must have a base case. (`if (n==0)` in your function)
2. A recursive algorithm must change its state and move toward the base case. (`n - 1` in your `n * fact(n - 1)`
3. A recursive algorithm must call itself, recursively. (`fact(n - 1)` in your function)

   `n` will be multiplied by a number returned by the function call `fact(n - 1)`.

To see what is going on behind the scene, you can use `print` function in Python.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as recursion. The way the "computer" interprets it is as a stack.

For example, consider `fact(5)`. This is how the computer interprets it:

```
push fact(5) to stack --> return 5 * fact(4), push fact(4) to stack
      where fact(4) --> 4 * fact(3), push fact(3) to stack
      where fact(3) --> 3 * fact(2), push fact(2) to stack
      where fact(2) --> 2 * fact(1), push fact(1) to stack
      where fact 1 --> 1 * fact(0), push fact(0) to stack
      where fact(0) --> 1. Pop from stack until empty.
```

Therefore, we are building up from our *base case*, which is that `fact(0) = 1`. Since we know `fact(1)` is `1 * fact(0)`, `fact(1) = 1`. `fact(2) = 2 * fact(1)`, so `fact(2) = 2`... `fact(5) = 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 120`.

Comment: So basically it doesn't read again the code, just the fact of return it push fact(x) to stack and goes down until hits fact (0) = 1?

Comment: @bl4ckch4ins precisely. And then it works its way up, using the defined base case.